# Duda sobre punteros, conversión

Tags: c++, punteros

Básicamente intente hacer esto mismo pero de otra forma:

```
int* a = (int*)4095;
```

Acá está la otra forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    void* a = std::malloc(sizeof(int));
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    int* b = (int*)a;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    *b = 4095;
    std::cout << *b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Esta es la dirección de *b: " << &(*b) << std::endl;
    int** c = (int**)a;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << *c << std::endl; //esto difiere con lo esperado: 0xfff
    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
0x1abf52e60a0
0x1abf52e60a0
4095
Esta es la direcci├│n de *b: 0x1abf52e60a0
0x1abf52e60a0
0x1ab00000fff
```

Que excepto la última línea es exactamente lo que esperaba (esperaba que fuera 0xfff la última línea). Extrañamente si lo pruebo en algún compilador online sí que sale lo esperado, por ejemplo en https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Aclaro cual es mi razonamiento así me dicen donde me equivoque:

| tipo | nombre | dirección | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| void* | a | 0x1 | 0x2 |
| int* | b | 0x7 | 0x2 |
| int | *b | 0x2 | 4095 |
| int** | c | 0x9 | 0x2 |
| int* | *c | 0x2 | 4095 |

Aclaro por las dudas que elegí 0x2,0x7 etc. por ninguna razón en particular. Lo único relevante para esta tabla (en términos de direcciones de memoria) es cuando es diferente y cuando se repite.
Para la vez particular que ejecute el programa (lo que puse como salida más arriba) podría reemplazar el 0x2 por 0x1abf52e60a0. Espero que se haya entendido el razonamiento que hice, desde ya muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: ¿Con qué compilador te da ese resultado inesperado?

Comment: Estoy en Windows 10 usando GCC (12.2.0), pero con clang (16.0.0) me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Extrañamente algo que note es que cada vez que lo ejecuto parece siempre terminar en fff la posición de memoria de lo que esperaba que fuera 0xfff. Osea, como mostré en la salida ahí termino siendo 0x1ab00000fff pero hasta ahora todas las veces que lo ejecute fue algo diferente pero siempre terminado en fff (desconozco si es casualidad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando ves un comportamiento inexplicable que para colmo, es diferente en otras plataformas y compiladores, muy probablemente estás en el terreno del [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).

---

Sospecho del uso de punteros a `void` y la conversión al estilo [c](/questions/tagged/c) como orígenes del comportamiento indefinido; si programamos con las herramientas de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) el código que muestras ni siquiera compila:

```
// 'new int' devuelve un puntero a 'int' no un puntero a 'void'.
int* a = new int;
std::cout << a << std::endl;

// No es necesario convertir a a 'int*', ¡ya lo es!.
int* b = a;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
*b = 4095;
std::cout << *b << std::endl;
std::cout << "Esta es la dirección de *b: " << &(*b) << std::endl;

// Error, no se puede convertir 'int*' a 'int**';
int** c = static_cast<int**>(a);
std::cout << c << std::endl;
std::cout << *c << std::endl;
```

La función `malloc` de C, no asegura el tipo ni la correcta inicialización de la memoria; devuelve memoria reservada en espacio dinámico sin tipo y sin inicializar. Lo bueno de la memoria sin tipo (con tipo `void`) es que puede interpretarse de cualquier manera… por eso puedes convertir un puntero a `void` en cualquier otro puntero sin que el compilador se queje. Lo malo de la memoria sin tipo es que puede interpretarse de cualquier manera… por eso puedes hacer conversiones que pueden no tener sentido.

Una de las conversiones que no tienen sentido es decirle al compilador que un puntero a entero (`int*`) es otro tipo de puntero (`int**`), esto se conoce como [*type puning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) y si no se hace adecuadamente da lugar al comportamiento indefinido como es tu caso, ya que al hacer esto:

```
int** c = (int**)a;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
std::cout << *c << std::endl; //esto difiere con lo esperado: 0xfff
```

Sucede lo siguiente:

- `a` es de tipo puntero a `void`, contiene una dirección de memoria a un espacio reservado dinámicamente de cuatro bytes, ese espacio contiene el valor `4095`.
- `c` es de tipo puntero a puntero a entero, se reinterpreta el valor de `a` (que **no es un puntero a puntero a entero**) como si fuese ese tipo. La expresión `*c` (contenido de `c`) nos devuelve un puntero a entero.
- En tu plataforma los punteros son de 64 bits y los enteros de 32, así que el valor `4095` se ha escrito en la parte baja del puntero dejando la parte alta sin tocar, de ahí que el valor `fff` tenga una especie de *prefijo*.

Si corregimos tu código para evitar el *type punning* quedaría así:

```
int* a = new int;
std::cout << a << std::endl;

int* b = a;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
*b = 4095;
std::cout << *b << "\nEsta es la dirección de *b: " << &(*b) << std::endl;

int** c = &a;
std::cout << c << '\n' << *c << std::endl;
```

El código anterior no tiene ningún error o alarma de compilación y produce la siguiente [salida](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%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%2BMAHgSPQh68PwOAfCYkiieQdqMc4UGWru2DqIxPKbMOry1Mx9AEHEpBkV4OC7pcBBsBRyw0EYwBKAhSGoeh0mCMIYgSJwMhyMIyhqJohH6FMRgmGgti2IYumHpAyzoCk9QiQAtJiJzQuYE7WBYcT8OgCmkKQBA4OF3xdHJWRuKKEwBFM4SRIM5TDFMBSZEIZX5OkDVMLMQxJFMDhFUIvTjN47QGN1Tg9GM/RVXMtXTP1uTldN42lB1UjLEo04bMtm5cP25CDsOo5cIcACykQAOIAOqHCBybgQAdBYN1aIcED4MQZD%2BtsPCLPwJ46Ms16UipqA8mQT4QM01mqMYtQiEg6DwoO84vgwLD1JDUT0DDcMI/wSNviAwDgRYLHoHeD6kNE7CbDjJOvokyE8pj8NKYDDykNZ%2B6hIDjSEIO/BOaI4iSO5/NeRou5%2BYYximMF1ihXE%2BWRdFWRxQlMLJTYqXpSOWU5Xl8ArWtbmjDzaPQ7DTPSZc2CbPO8L6Sk5mbdtu0ZdwuCA8DpCHOoAAcIaxT%2Bl0Ooct2BhA44a3YhwvSQXtzl9C5Losq7rpt27kGZlQbi7e5cAeR6J6ef1XigymqbHoPg0opsY%2Bb2PE6TRio1DtdY7uuPDATAYN7T5OUxzHekPToh18zjGs%2Bzeec4x3ORBz/MuULsgiyoYu%2BSARMBdLKV2Dp8v6yOStCCr5KJertgWCwGU67likRSsazrV15KRDXjP11bnAbnbLAO6JPZ9h3IRfa7ty5vV9v7QOV0Q73TDhHEK0dCCx3ep9b6SdlhIGuDgJIBVexcHTpnbOu59r52POg8ga4s6bW2EAvaHMfrLk2hYfgZkfYKhugqH20gfYWEqNIBUH0ggyBCDnEhhdfrnhLiAXEKQeSg0HhTDg3AIEB2kEHa6sD%2BDYCQWQXKBgF6CzcsveQosfLDglj/P%2BfAAFbVoa7Lgw9ZFvHQDQI6p0LrQNDg9J6XhG6JBQQnBhydyCYJYNg6gKceBaA3HgghUgtAPR4JUHgQRpBZxDDwn2lQLA%2Bx2sQjmh4yFFxsTQvJwD6HkKyhkVw0ggA%3D):

```
0xb6aeb0
0xb6aeb0
4095
Esta es la dirección de *b: 0xb6aeb0
0x7ffca23f2528
0xb6aeb0
```

Comment: Basándome en lo que pusiste se me ocurrió que con llanamente cambiar todos los lugares donde aparece "int" en mi código a "long long int" (así es un tipo de dato de 64 bits) debería funcionar y lo hizo :D. ¡¡¡Gracias!!!. Me quedo una duda sobre una parte de lo que dijiste: "así que el valor 4095 *se ha escrito en la parte baja del puntero* dejando la parte alta sin tocar, de ahí que el valor fff tenga una especie de prefijo.". ¿Porque se escribió en la parte baja del puntero ? Intuitivamente hubiera esperado que se escribiera en la parte alta de dicho.

Comment: En la parte que pusiste "Si corregimos tu código para evitar el type punning quedaría así:". No veo que ese código que pusiste haga lo que yo quería en un primer momento, que en definitiva es tener un puntero que apunte a la dirección 0xfff, sin hacerlo de la forma directa. Digo en la salida muestra que *c apunta a "0xb6aeb0". Por cierto, seré curioso, cual es la terminología en español para "type punning", pasa que no me llevo bien con el inglés.

Comment: @Sturm0 "*¿Por qué se escribió en la parte baja del puntero?*", es difícil de decir ya que estás en el terreno del comportamiento indefinido y cada compilador puede decidir hacer las cosas como le venga bien… habrá una explicación para este comportamiento pero será tan específica del compilador y tan técnica que no sabría explicarla, probablemente mirando el código ASM generado aporte alguna pista.

Comment: @Sturm0 para "*tener un puntero que apunte a la dirección `0xfff`*" no debes complicarte tanto, te basta con `auto a = reinterpret_cast<int*>(4095);`. Respecto a la traducción de *type punning* es complicado, no me consta que exista un término en español; yo personalmente lo traduciría como "*bromear con los tipos*" (pun es broma en inglés) o "*jugar/trastear con los tipos*".

Comment: Uh, una lástima que sea difícil saber porque se escribió en la parte baja del puntero. Y actualmente no tengo ni idea de ASM.
'para "tener un puntero que apunte a la dirección 0xfff" no debes complicarte tanto, te basta con auto a = reinterpret_cast<int*>(4095);'. 

Sí, de hecho comencé la pregunta poniendo "Básicamente intenté hacer esto mismo pero de otra forma: int* a = (int*)4095".
En cuanto a la razón de meterme en este embrollo es llanamente que se me ocurrió que debería funcionar también y por eso lo probé.

Comment: Respecto a la traducción de "type punning" me parece que la voy a llamar "broma de tipos" o uso el término en inglés, al menos hasta que haya algún término en español oficial para referirse a ello.